# Why is scripting not available in my version of Enterprise Architect?

Tags: scripting, enterprise-architect

I have tried to follow the (nice) webinar how to do scripting with EA ([Scripting Introduction](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/webinar/partners/scripting/scripting-introduction-bellekens.html)), and don't have the option to try that locally.

My EA installation tells me that I have the corporate edition installed, and the [EA help](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/the_scripter_window.html) tells me that scripting is available up from the corporate edition. What do I have to do to enable scripting in EA?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on scripting in the options

[image]

and you should be ready to go.

You can use the API also from outside EA.

Comment: Also check the option `View | Perspectives | Menu Sets` and make sure to select the option *complete*

Comment: Thank's a lot! It was such easy, just go through all menus and search for the menu item (today). I get sometimes lost in the menu structure of EA.

Comment: Hehe. Wait for v13. The ribbons make it even worse (at least for me, knowing where to search in the menu jungle).